# Iterating over multiple variables in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to add users to the system from a file. The file looks exactly like this:

```
user@domain.com password 1
user2@domain.com baddpassword 2
```

The numbers are their IDs. Its coming from a mysql db and I need to do something with those variables too so I need 4 variables. The USER, PASS, FIRSTID (being 1) and LASTID (being the last ID of the mysql dump in this case, 2. This is considering more than 2 entries at a time)

So far what I have is this:

```
for USER in $(awk -F@ 'NR>1 {print $1}' /root/users_w_pass)
do
    for PASS in $(awk 'NR>1 {print $2}' /root/users_w_pass)
    do
        useradd $USER -d /home/$USER -m
        echo "$USER:$PASS" | chpasswd
        ...


    done
done
```

When running this, the password does not get added to the corresponding user and I have no idea on how I am supposed to do that since I thought it would work but I can see how it doesn't. It seems to loop the password. Also I am creating files and assigning ACLs for each, so running `newusers` on a file won't work here, especially that there is a third column as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [don't want to read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). The proper way to do it is to use [`while` with `read`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). The `read` builtin can automatically parse fields per line if they're separated by whitespace (spaces and tabs). The `-r` option makes sure that backslashes aren't interpreted while reading:

```
while read -r user password id; do
    # strip the @domain part from username
    user="${user%%@*}"
    useradd "$user" -d "/home/$user" -m
    echo "$user:$password" | chpasswd
    # and so on
done < your_input_file
```

Also note that you shouldn't use all-uppercase variables. `$USER` is already reserved for *your* username.

Comment: I appreciate the update answer. I should have been more clear on the ID part also. What I need is that the first line, in this case being id number 1 should be set to $firstid and the last entry (in this case there are only two entries here) so we use 2 for this example, should be set to $lastid. The reason is that at the end of the script, I need to run a mysql command to "UPDATE table set status='1' WHERE id BETWEEN $firstid AND $lastid". This script runs every hour. So every hour, only the users with status=0 are dumped to a file similar to the output we started with.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just run `set status='1' where id=$id` for every added user? Of course it has a little bit of an impact performance-wise. Otherwise I'd use `head -n 1` and `tail -n 1` to find the first and last ID *after* the loop has run.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Yes, that would be easier. For some reason I dont know why I thought I'd be setting potentially new users to status=1. Will test this momentarily and return with a nice big green checkmark for your awesome help.

Comment: Worked like an absolute charm. Thank you very much for the help!